# Um BruteForce mais eficiente

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmo

Tenho um código que fiz em alguns minutos que era pra ser um "BruteForce". funciona, mas depois de 3 caracteres, ele já demora muito.

Tive algumas ideias para deixar mais eficiente, como salvar em uma variavel a senha que já foi testada, ou em um arquivo. mas isso não ia fazer muita diferença (alem de gastar muito recurso da maquina).
Tem alguma forma de deixar mais eficiente? mesmo uma senha simples de 3 caracteres, todas minusculas, facilitando de todas as formas, demora cerca de 25 segundos

```
from time import time
start = time()
import random
#random.choice(alphabet)

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
maxLeng = 5
password = input('Password\n>')

possible = ''


while possible != password:
    possible = possible + random.choice(alphabet)

    if len(possible)>=maxLeng:
        possible=''

    if possible == password:
        print('The password is: '+str(possible))
        end=time()
        timet=end-start
        print('Found in '+str(int(timet))+' seconds') #  "str(int(timet))" para arrendondar o tempo
        break
    else:
        print(possible)
input()
```

Um exemplo do quanto é ineficiente: meu script precisou de 290518 tentativas para achar "abc", um script bem feito, por alguém que sabe alguma coisa sobre esse assunto, precisou de 704 tentativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando chutar senhas aleatoriamente, usando o `random.choice(alphabet)`. Dessa forma você não mantém nenhum controle sobre as senhas já tentadas, ou sobre a ordenação dos chutes. Não tenho certeza sobre o termo técnico, mas por mim, chutar de forma completamente aleatória não seria nem chamado de força bruta.

Porque você não tenta, chutar as senhas de forma ordenada? Isto é, primeiro tentar "a", depois "b" até "z". Para aí então chutar "aa", "ab" até "az". Se você tem dificuldade para entender essa lógica, pode pensar como se estivesse contando: Primeiro contamos de 0 a 9, para depois contar de 10 a 19,  depois de 20 a 29, etc.
Para verificar a senha, poderiamos também fazer `if (password in respostasPossiveis):` e não precisaríamos desse for adicional, nem dessa variável "achado", mas de forma didática, preferi comparar uma a uma manualmente.
Para fazer a criação das respostasPossíveis, eu utilizei compreensão de listas, mas você pode fazer do jeito que você quiser. Segue o exemplo:

```py
from time import time
start = time()
achado=0
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
maxLeng = 5
password = input('Password\n>')
respostasPossiveis=alphabet

for i in range(1,maxLeng+1):
    #print (respostasPossiveis)
    for x in respostasPossiveis:
        if (password == x):
            print('The password is: '+str(x))
            end=time()
            timet=end-start
            print('Found in '+str(int(timet))+' seconds') #  "str(int(timet))" para arrendondar o tempo
            achado=1;
            break
    if (achado==1 or maxLeng==i):
        break
    respostasPossiveis=[a+b for a in respostasPossiveis for b in alphabet]
input()
```

Claro que varia de computador para computador, mas a senha mais demorada de todas, "zzzzz", demorou aqui 34 segundos:

```
The password is: zzzzz
Found in 34 seconds
```